# store token in cookie or local storage in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, local-storage

I have a reactjs login application and I want to store the **token** I get from the API to **cookie** or **local storage**, the code below is the basic authentication POST method that I use. can you show me how to store token in the cookie or local storage in reactjs? Which one is better?

```
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const data = "access_token=value";
    const url = "https://api";
    xhr.open("POST", url);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.setRequestHeader(
      "Authorization",
      "Basic " + btoa("Username:Password")
    );
    xhr.send(data);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
      if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        console.log(xhr.response);
      }
    };
```

my response has a token parameter and the value of it.

Comment: you could simply save the token in the local storage by `localStorage.setItem('token', response.token)` and to retrieve pass the key to get as `let token=localStorage.getItem('token')`. You might use third-party libraries to access localstorage or cookies

Comment: I recommand localstorage too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally in web app, we used a localstorage or session to our token id in our web app. so, you can used localstorage or session. based on your project requirement you can used any one.

**Exmple**

```
localStorage.setItem('variableName', data);
```

you can save this way in localstorage.